# Save Sketched lines in LocalStorage

Tags: react-native, expo

Sorry im posting this here

I want to save the info of each line i drew on canvas(the save action would be called onChange)
so i can retrieve this data and draw it on canvas again in case the user change screen or something.

I'm using expo-pixi to draw a image and sketch over it

```
onChangeAsync = async (param) => {
// here i want on change code i get the line informantion and store it

}
onLayout = async ({
        nativeEvent: {
            layout: { width, height },
        },
    }) => {
        this.setState({
            layoutWidth: width,
            layoutHeight: height,
        })
        this.onReady();
    }
onReady = async () => {
        const { layoutWidth, layoutHeight, points } = this.state;
        this.sketch.graphics = new PIXI.Graphics();

        if (this.sketch.stage) {

            if (layoutWidth && layoutHeight) {
                const background = await PIXI.Sprite.fromExpoAsync(this.props.image);
                background.width = layoutWidth * scaleR;
                background.height = layoutHeight * scaleR;

                this.sketch.stage.addChild(background);
                this.sketch.renderer._update();
            }
        }
    };

// The sketch component is pretty much as the example which comes with the lib
<Sketch
 ref={ref => (this.sketch = ref)}
 style={styles.sketch}
 strokeColor={this.state.strokeColor}
 strokeWidth={this.state.strokeWidth}
 strokeAlpha={1}
 onChange={this.onChangeAsync}
 onReady={this.onReady}
/>
```

Does anyone have any clue? im kind of desperate

Thanks

Comment: In order for us to help you, we need to show us the codes you are not solving.

Comment: I've tried to put in better words here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56978080/expo-pixi-save-stage-children-on-app-higher-state-and-retrieve